# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence even though I added dependencies

Tags: java, maven, jpa, model-view-controller, eclipse-jee

Although I added the jpa dependencies as well as i created the persistence.xml file in the correct location, i can't help but get this error.
Note that the database table was successfully created with a java application test class
Connecting with the persistence in the controller

```
    private static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("unit");
    private static EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
    private static EntityTransaction transactionObj = entityManager.getTransaction();
```

Here are the dependencies I used in the pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Here is the project structure [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FIvx.png)

Comment: Note that the `javax` package name was changed to `jakarta`. Use `jakarta.whatever` instead of `javax.whatever`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and I was able to run the project successfully.

Right Click on your project -> select Properties -> select "Deployment Assembly" -> Add -> Select Java Build Path Entries -> Select Maven Dependencies -> Apply and Close

Restart the server and it should work